# JLabel won't turn opaque even after writing a code?

Tags: java, swing, background, jlabel

I have a label and a button in my JFrame form. What i want to do is this- when a user clicks the button, the label attains a black color.

I went on the form, right clicked the label and set background to black, then I double clicked the JButton and in the

`private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)`

method i wrote

`lbl.setOpaque(true);`

but even after i click the button on the test run, it won't turn black! Another thing i noticed was that if I use the `setToolTipText()` method (which is used to show a string when hovered upon) and then remove the mouse from the label (ie, un-hover the label) the area stays black, which was intended.

Does anyone have a reason why this "glitch" is happening?

EDIT:- here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSVsq.png), if it helps.

UPDATE:- I tried your method @coinbird, it still doesn't work! It is the same problem again, turns black after hovering and removing the cursor..

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class background_test2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form background_test2
 */
public background_test2() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    lbl.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    lbl.setText("Hover HERE!!");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(151, 151, 151)
                    .addComponent(lbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 155, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(lbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Test");
    lbl2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    lbl2.setOpaque(true);


}                                        


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background_test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background_test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background_test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background_test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new background_test2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });



}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lbl;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Test");
lbl2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
lbl2.setOpaque(true);
```

That code doesn't do anything.

You create a new label, but you never add the label to the frame.

You need to make the label that you add to the frame opaque:

```
lbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
lbl.setOapaque(true);
```

Every time you ask a question post a proper [Minimal and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see exactly what you are doing. There is no way we could guess that you are creating a new label in the ActionListener.

Comment: thanks @camickr i'll keep them in mind.. that being said, the code STILL doesn't produce the desired output. I click the button but the label won't go black! Could you try the code once yourself and see if it works for you? Thanks!

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw, the code you posted is wrong. You have updated the code so no I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the background color before `lbl.setOpaque(true);` will do anything

`lbl.setBackground(Color.Black);`

Make sure you're doing this in your code. I like to write it out manually rather than trust the GUI toolbox thing.

Here's some more info. This website looks like junk, but the info is good: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/setopaque.html

Comment: any idea why i can't get it to work even though i did set in the that GUI toolbox? i mean it DOES turn black after the setToolTipText() method..

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Let's troubleshoot. Does it look OK if you take it outside of the button click?

`JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Test");
      lb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      lb.setOpaque(true);`

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw also make sure you have imported `java.awt.Color`

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Also please share more of your code. Are you using the `.isPressed()` method?

Comment: please excuse my lack of knowledge since i haven't tried working without the GUI before. It shows an error <identifier> expected for the last 2 lines of code. Something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw I don't know what your last two lines of code are. You're going to have to show some more code in your original post.

Comment: please see the update, i've attached the entire code